# Multiply Corresponding Matrices in Separate Arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have two arrays, A and B, each containing n square mxm matrices; that is, the dimensions of both A and B are `dim=c(m,m,n)`. What is the most efficient way using R to obtain an array of the same dimension of the product `A[,,j]%*%B[,,j]%*%t(A[,,j])` for every j between one and n?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method using `Map`:

```
# create some data
set.seed(1234)
A <- replicate(3, matrix(rnorm(4), 2))
B <- replicate(3, matrix(rnorm(4), 2))

# get the results
Map(function(j) A[,,j]%*%B[,,j]%*%t(A[,,j]), 1:3)
```

The arrays are 2X2X3. `Map` applies your function to each of the three 3rd dimensional matrices in A and B.

You could also use `lapply`:

```
lapply(1:3, function(j) A[,,j]%*%B[,,j]%*%t(A[,,j]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had considered using `lapply`, but I wasn't sure if there was a faster method.

Comment: `lapply` is pretty fast in terms of looping. Also, as the size of your matrices grow, the bulk of the computation time will be in the matrix algebra.